# Is conditional inheritance possible?

Tags: typescript, oop, inheritance

I am brand new to OOP paradigm and I was wondering whether conditional inheritance is somehow possible in TS, that could eliminate the need to double write the code. The following is what I have in mind. Any recommendation would be more than welcome.

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface Animal {
  genre: string;
  age: number;
}

abstract class Base {

  private velocity: number = 1;

  run() {
    // if Person extends base return velocity * 0.2; ??
    return this.velocity * 0.4;
  }
}

class Human extends Base implements Person {
  ...
}

class Dog extends Base implements Animal{
  ...
}

let marie = new Human('Marie', 22);
marie.run() //should be 0.2

let bennie = new Dog(...);
bennie.run() // should be 0.4
```

Is there anyway it could work or the only possibility is to declare the method as abstract in the base class and thereafter implement it for both cases separately?

Answer (score 2):

The usual way would be to hold a multiplier that's set during initialization, perhaps by having the subclass provide it to the superclass:

```
abstract class Base {

  private velocity: number = 1;

  constructor(private multiplier) {           // <===
  }

  run() {
    return this.velocity * this.multiplier;
  }
}

class Human extends Base implements Person {
  constructor() {
    super(0.2);                               // <===
  }
}

class Dog extends Base implements Animal{
  constructor() {
    super(0.4);                               // <===
  }
}
```

There are various ways to provide the multiplier, but that's one example.

Comment: Indeed in this example it seems to work. But I need to pass a type to the parent abstract method and based on the type passed, return some very specific property which apply only to that type.i.e. `class Person {...}

abstract class Base {
  constructor(private t: Person | Animal) {};
  run() {
    if(this.t instanceof Person) {
      return ('Run Forest run!!!');
    }  
    return ('Run Dog run away!');
  }
}

class Human extends Base implements Person {
    constructor(...) {
        super(new Person())
  };
}` To my taste it is a bit of an anti pattern.